# How to get ML Kit on Android onDevice language download size?

Tags: android, google-mlkit

As in official google text translation app show language size before downloading onDevice language.

I look at documentation but did not find any thing related size.

Comment: I don't remember there's a demo providing the size, could you provide the app link?

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.translate

Comment: Sorry, I misread it's some demo apps from ML Kit. Right, ML Kit currently does not provide this functionality. We'll evaluate it internally.